# How do I convert January to February in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm creating a budget starting this month (October). I drag October to the next column but it just fills it as October. How do I make it so it goes to November instead?

Answer (score 0):

Excel likes to have a pattern to follow: I would try having 01/10/2019 (1 October) then the 01/11/2019 (first November) in the second cell, then Excel will know that you want to add months to your list.

You could also do `=DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+1,DAY(A1))` which would add a month each time.

Hopefully one of these will work for you  (if you extend the date to show DAY, it will probably be 01/10, 02/10, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Excel's fill handle tool(bottom right dot on a cell) works only with series.
For example, we need to generate 1-10 numbers..Typing just 1 and dragging will not generate the series.

You must have starting 2 elements of the series i.e.1 in one cell, 2 in next cell.
Select both cells having 1 and 2, drag.This will generate series.

In the same way, type January in one cell, February in other cell, select both and use the fill handle to drag.
 This should solve your problem.